# Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

I am essentially trying to match a series of cells from 2 worksheets and obtained values from a corresponding column.

When I run this code, I get an error:

> object doesn't support this property or method

**My Code**

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim rowcount As Integer
Dim target As Variant

rowcount = Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Count
For i = 1 To rowcount + 1
    target = Application.Match(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6) & "-" & Cells(i, 5) & "-" & Cells(i, 4) & "-" & Cells(i, 3), Worksheets(14).Range("A6:A3000"), 0)
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6) & "-" & Cells(i, 5) & "-" & Cells(i, 4) & "-" & Cells(i, 3) = _
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 6) & "-" & Cells(i + 1, 5) & "-" & Cells(i + 1, 4) & "-" & Cells(i + 1, 3) Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 17) = Worksheets(14).target.Offset(0, 10)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the Row count, you need to use the syntax: 
`rowcount = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count` , also it's better to use `Long` than `Integer`.

Also, you need to trap a possible error when unable to find a successful match with the `Application.Match` function, do it by using `If Not IsError(target) Then`.

**Note**: try to avoid using `ActiveSheet`, instead use fully qualified worksheet, by using `Worksheets("YourSheetName")` in your code.

**Code**

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim rowcount As Long
Dim target As Variant

rowcount = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
For i = 1 To rowcount + 1
    target = Application.Match(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6) & "-" & Cells(i, 5) & "-" & Cells(i, 4) & "-" & Cells(i, 3), Worksheets(14).Range("A6:A3000"), 0)
    If Not IsError(target) Then ' successful Match
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6) & "-" & Cells(i, 5) & "-" & Cells(i, 4) & "-" & Cells(i, 3) = _
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 6) & "-" & Cells(i + 1, 5) & "-" & Cells(i + 1, 4) & "-" & Cells(i + 1, 3) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 17) = Worksheets(14).target.Offset(0, 10)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to find a Match !"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but -1 for just recommending changes to make the code more like your own style, without even attempting to fix the OP's error.  (Let me know if you choose to address the OP's issue, and I will reverse the dv.)

Answer (score 0):

`target` is not a Property or Method of a `Worksheets` object.

I believe you need to change `Worksheets(14).target.Offset(0, 10)` to `Worksheets(14).Range("A5").Offset(target, 10)`.

---

You should also be consistent in your coding.  In your code you have things like `ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 6) & "-" & Cells(i + 1, 5) ...`, where you specifically qualify `Cells(i + 1, 6)` to be on `ActiveSheet` but allow `Cells(i + 1, 5)` to default to being on the `ActiveSheet`.  Although it works, it will get very confusing if you ever need to reread your code later on.